# Set scale of axis in plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am unable to scale the y-axis. My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pt
import numpy as np
fig = pt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
sample = 20
x=np.arange(sample)
y=10*np.sin(2*np.pi*x/20)
pt.plot(x,y)
pt.show()
```

The y axis has scale of 5. I'm trying to make it 1.
[image: The output snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using `set_yticks` this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
sample = 20
x=np.arange(sample)
y=10*np.sin(2*np.pi*x/20)

ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1, 1.0)) # setting the ticks
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
fig.show()
```

Which produces this image wherein `y-axis` has a scale of 1.

[image]

Comment: You can also use the ticker API http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-locating which lets you specify how the tick locations are decided in a more flexible way.  ex `ax.get_yaxis().set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))`