# Trouble to specify a custom x and y axes scale in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale

I am trying to use matplotlib to reproduce a plot with a similar axis calling of the image below:

[image: Plot to replicate]

I was trying to use the `ax.set_xscale` and `ax.set_yscale`, but I am unsure which option i should use to make the major ticker to follow the desired pattern e.g

axis x --> 0.1 , 0.3 , 1 , 3 , 10 , 30 ....
axis y --> 0.02 , 0.06, 0.1 , 0.2 ,0.6, 1 ,2, 6....

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090513/set-scale-of-axis-in-plot-using-matplotlib) answer your question?

Comment: I am afraid not… the axes seems to be in a customised logitorim scale but it is not the convencional ones you see around ( based 10, e or 2)

Comment: You will probably need this one:   https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.FuncScale class matplotlib.scale.FuncScale(axis, functions) . It seems that the x-scale is a logarithmic one with a base of about 28